# Dijkstra's algorithm to compute shortest paths using k edges?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dynamic-programming, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

I am aware of using Bellman-Ford on a graph $G=(V,E)$ with no negative cycles to find the single-source single-destination shortest paths from source $s$ to target $t$ (both in $V$) using at most $k$ edges. Assuming we have no negative edge weights at all, can we use Dijkstra's algorithm for the same?

**My thoughts/algorithm:**
I was wondering if instead of having a $dist[u$] array (storing the best known distance from s to u), we could use a $dist[u][k]$ table to store the best known distance from $s$ to $u$ using at most $k$ edges (dynamic programming maybe?), and similarly have the priority queue with $(u,n)$ tuples as keys. We can then terminate the algorithm when the tuple popped off the priority queue is $(t,n)$ where t is the target destination and $n <= k$?

Comment: As far as I remember you can use Dijkstra's algorithm instead of Bellman-Ford when you don't have edges with negative distance in you graph; I'd have to take a closer look at both the algorithms to elaborate more though

Comment: 1. Does the graph have any edges with negative length?  2. What time complexity are you looking for?  What's the fastest algorithm you were able to come up with?  There's a standard solution based on "the product construction" that increases the running time by a factor of $k$; is that of interest to you?

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/43099/755 for a loosely related but not identical problem.

Comment: @D.W. thanks for the response! 1. No, only >= 0 edge weights. 2. The time complexity I'm looking for is $O(k*(V+E)*log(V))$ and that's the complexity of my algorithm too, but I'm not sure if it's right.
Also, please could you link me to the 'product construction' solution?

Comment: OK.  Please edit the question to include this information, and also present your algorithm.  We want questions to be self-contained, so people don't need to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: I edited to remove a potential confusing point for readers: Bellman-Ford only requires that the graph have no negative cycles; you want to assume more.

Comment: Note that your target running time, assuming the bound is tight, is *worse* than Bellman-Ford, which runs in time  $O(|V| + k \cdot |E|)$ here.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/118977/755

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the graph has no negative edges, the problem can be solved in $O(k \cdot (|V|+|E|) \lg |E|)$ time using Dijkstra's algorithm combined with a product construction.  We construct a new graph $G'=(V',E')$ with vertex set $V' = V \times \{0,1,2,\dots,k\}$ and edge set

$$E' = \{((v,i), (w,i+1)) : (v, w) \in E\}.$$

In other words, for each edge $v \to w$ in $G$, we have edge $(v,i) \to (w,i+1)$ for all $i$ in $G'$.

Now use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path in $G'$ from $(s,0)$ to a vertex of the form $(t,i)$ where $i \le k$.  This will be the shortest path in $G$ that uses at most $k$ edges.

Comment: Since this is slower than Bellman-Ford (in theory, and probably also in practice because we have to construct a new, rather large graph first), I don't see much point -- but the OP asked for it.

Comment: @Raphael, yeah, it does seem a bit pointless to me too.